# How do i make changes to an html element through jquery ajax permanent so it remains after refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Im a beginner in codeigniter and am trying to make sort of an ecommerce website.

Now whenever a user clicks on the "Add to cart" button in my view, i use jquery ajax to send a request to a controller function which returns two variables count(total items in cart) and total(the total value of items in cart) as a string and then i modify a div with class .cart to simply display a string containing the two variables.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#addtocart").click(function(){


    var id = $("#product_id").val();
    var qty = $("#quantity").val(); 

$.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url('cart/addtocart'); ?>",
        data: {id: id , qty:qty },
        type: 'POST',       
        success: function(name) {

            $(".cart").html(name); //This is the div where show number of items in cart and total value of cart

        }
    });

    });
})
```

But the string doesnt remain when i refresh the page or go to another page. i want the change made through jquery permanent and remain their regardless where the user navigates in the website. I need direction on how to accomplish this. if i need to save it to my database, then what and how to go about it

Comment: For transmitting values through different controllers, you should use sessions. In controller where you make calculation, after you calculate the price and before echo back to browser, set sesstion `$this->session->set_userdata('price', 'some_value');`. Don't forget to delete certain session data when needed. Also, I suggest to take a look of CI_Cart.php class (library) because there is much more simplified dealing with cart items.

Comment: I will look into the cart class but u misunderstood my question. im using session variables already. My question was that when i hit the refresh button i still want the modification done to an html element through jquery to stay, not disappear. i want that modification to be permanent

Comment: If they user reloads the page, then you could simply output those values _from_ the server – it has the values already, and it presumably generates the element you want to show them in in the first place – so why not output them right there and then?

Answer (score 0):

use post method like

```
$.post('url',{var:value,var2:value},function(data){
  $('.cart').html(data);
});

$('.cart').html(data); or $('.cart').load(data);
```